# Roboteq BLDC Motor Controller Serial Communication Issue

Tags: arduino, serial-port, serial-communication, ttl

I know there are several people out there who have succeeded with serial communication between Arduino and Roboteq.
I have been struggling for a long time now and cannot get it to work.
Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong.

**Roboteq Brushless DC Motor Controller**: SBL1360

**Arduinos used**: Uno, Nano, Due

**RS232 to TTL Converter Modules used**:
[ElecFreaks](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/rs232-to-ttl-module-p-768.html), 
[Seeed](https://www.seeedstudio.com/RS232-to-TTL-Converter-Module-p-1684.html)

**Cable configuration**:

```
DB9 Female To PC        DB15 Male To Controller
Pin 2 (RX Data)     -   Pin 2 (Data Out)
Pin 3 (TX Data)     -   Pin 3 (Data In)
Pin 5 (GND)         -   Pin 5 (GND)
```

**Setting up Roboteq via Roborun+ PC Utility Console**:

*Disable watchdog*

```
^RWD 0
```

*Save Configuration*

```
%EESAV
```

**Commands**:

*Read Motor Amps*

```
?A
```

*Go to Speed or to Relative Position*

```
!G 1 500
```

**Sample Arduino Code**:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.print("!G 1 500_");
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Troubleshooting**:

*Reading and writing commands using Putty Serial*

1. PC -> USB to RS232 -> RS232 to BOB15 -> SBL1360 - Works
2. PC -> Arduino -> TTL to RS232 -> RS232 to USB -> PC - Works
3. Arduino -> TTL to RS232 -> RS232 to BOB15 -> SBL1360 - Does not work

I have experimented with different Arduinos, different RS232 to TTL converters and different serial communication libraries, flipped RX/TX wires, still no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Roboteq SBL1360](http://roboteq.com/index.php/component/virtuemart/276/sbl1360-detail?Itemid=1234)

Comment: [Roboteq Controllers User Manual](http://roboteq.com/index.php/docman/motor-controllers-documents-and-files/documentation/user-manual/272-roboteq-controllers-user-manual-v17/file)